# What's the meaning of "front"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this statement:

> You need to talk to your partner. You are in this together and you can figure it out. I understand about the cats but rehoming your cats isn't as catastrophic for your family as your death - not by a long long way. The life insurance isn't a substitute for having your around. If you have to declare bankruptcy, then you do - and you will pick up and recover. It isn't the end of the world even though it feels like it right now.
>
> You need to see a doctor about your depression and get some advice on
>   the debt **front**. Many many many successful business owners have
>   bankruptcy in their past - it is a very common thing. You are not a
>   failure and you can come back from this. Don't think about suicide as
>   an option.

What's the meaning of *front* in "debt front"?

Comment: The definition you want is [2: "b (1) :  a stand on an issue :  policy (2) :  an area of activity or interest <progress on the educational front>"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/front).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"On the X front" is an expression which means "regarding X". In this case it is a very natural way to phrase the sentence.

For example, this sentence can also be written as

> You need to see a doctor about your depression, and get some advice regarding your debts.